# Backbone-on-rails/jasmine-rails - Backbone is undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, backbone.js, jasmine

I am trying to set up tests for my backbonejs app (using backbone-on-rails gem) with jasmine-rails gem.

I have the following in `jasmine.yml`:

```
src_files:
 - "**/*.{js,coffee}"

stylesheets:

helpers:
  - "helpers/**/*.{js,coffee}"

spec_files:
  - "**/*[Ss]pec.{js,coffee}"

src_dir: "app/assets"

spec_dir: spec/javascripts

asset_paths:
 - "vendor/assets/javascripts
```

Running the specs, I get the following error in my Javascript console:

**Uncaught ReferenceError: Backbone is not defined**

It appears it can't load backbone itself...

Any suggestions?